# Disable Send To and Download a Copy options for files?

Tags: document-library

I'd like to completely restrict the Send To and Download a Copy options found under the Documents tab in Document Libraries for all users.  How can I accomplish this?

**Edit:**  I should make myself a little more clear.  I just want to stop users from creating copies and moving files to locations where they don't belong.  I understand that as long as a user can see the contents of a file there will always be ways to copy that data and/or move it.  What I'm interested in is disabling the tools that make this easy for my users.

Comment: While you can do this, however you wont achieve the results you are probably looking for.  What is it you are actually trying to achieve (I don't want to assume here).

Comment: What I want to do is prevent users from making copies of or moving files.  I also plan on restricting access to the Open in Explorer feature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To disable buttons in server ribbon look at @Brage answer but...

... by disabling Send To and Download a Copy buttons in Documents tab of Server ribbon you achieve absolutely nothing. Users will still have both options available under list item ECB menu.

There is article on MSDN on [How to: Hide a Menu Item in the ECB from SharePoint List Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc768565.aspx) but **it's a complete nonsense that this article has ever been written at all!** This is not even bad practice - it's something you never ever do.

If I am guessing right (please also look at @Jesus Shelby comment to your question) you are trying to forbid users to download files from document library. This cannot be done - if user have read permission he can download file. If my guess is wrong please provide more details.

Comment: I've had that come up too. "we want to upload some files but don't want users to be able to get to them or download them" My response: the web doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 5):

You can remove the buttons from the Ribbon. A walkthrough on how to do this can be found here: [Walkthrough: Removing a Button from the Server Ribbon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff408060.aspx)

I think the code for removing send to and downnload a copy will be the following (not tested):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
      <CustomAction Id="RemoveRibbonButton"  Location="CommandUI.Ribbon">
      <CommandUIExtension>
        <CommandUIDefinitions>
          <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Documents.Share.EmailItemLink" />
          <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Documents.Copies.Download" />
        </CommandUIDefinitions>
      </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

A list of the names of the ribbon control can be found here:[Default Server Ribbon Customization Locations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537543.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Definitely not going to be able to do that.  You can lock it down all you want, but if they can see the information they can copy it.  Even if you remove all the options, disable right click, and convert office docs to HTML.  There still is nothing stopping them from saving the page, or disabling JavaScript, or even just re-writing the information.

What you have is a communication problem, not a technical one.

You need to set standards in your policies and educate your users on the use of the information.  If you don't want them downloading local copies or sending via email, it needs to be communicated and enforced from the business side, not IT.

It may take some doing but you will probably have to "manage" and re-set expectations.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you want, but you can configure Send To connections in Central Admin.

This is used for content organizer and Drop-off libraries:

Central admin > General Application settings > Configure Send to Connections

More info on [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee424395.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link, you won't need to disable the sub menu and its options. Using RMS will help you managing user rights and permissions over files and docs on a SharePoint list or library.

[Micorsoft Office: Apply Information Rights Management to a list or library](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/apply-information-rights-management-to-a-list-or-library-HA010154148.aspx)

Comment: This actually addresses another question I had as well, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add a Script editor to the page by clicking on Edit or Edit Page option on the right side > Insert > Web Part > Media and Content > Script Editor > Click on  Add.

Then click on Edit Web Part of Script Editor.

Then click on Edit Snippets.

Paste the following code in the embed window:

```
<style>
/* 1. Download a Copy Box, 2.Send To Box */
#Ribbon\.Documents\.Copies-LargeMedium-0, #Ribbon\.Documents\.Copies-LargeMedium-1-0
{
    display:none;
}
</style>
```

Click on Insert.

Save and Refresh the Page.

[image]

"Send To" and "Download a Copy" will be removed from the Ribbon.