# Edit ECB menu items for non-code & code method

Tags: ecb-menu

How to edit ECB menu items in SharePoint 2007 using non-code method & code method?

Comment: What is the problem and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What I would achieve is that I do not want some end-user to be able to use some of the ECB menu item and therefore I would either hide those menu items or just delete those menu item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found another work around using the SPServices (http://spservices.codeplex.com/).

Rather than allow the user to have direct access to the SharePoint List (and thus having the "power" to use the ECB menu), I will use a aspx file that provide interface with the SharePoint List via SPServices.

Answer (score 1):

There is no non-code method for this.

[Jan Tielen’s three-part series](http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2009/09/03/customizing-the-sharepoint-ecb-with-javascript-part-1.aspx) is nice resource for adding items on ECB.

However hiding item can be only done by changing `core.js` and this is something you don't do. Take a look at my answer here: [Disable Send To and Download a Copy options for files?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17599/disable-send-to-and-download-a-copy-options-for-files/17605#17605)

Comment: Got your point. Is there other solution beside the changing of the core.js? (Maybe using the permission or etc..)

Answer (score 0):

This article can also be helpful  : http://extreme-sharepoint.com/2011/10/29/hide-menu-ecb/

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)