# Restrict permissions for PowerPivot

Tags: permissions, powerpivot

Is it possible to configure the permissions for a Power Pivot library such that users can reference the Power Pivots as a data source for Excel or Power View, but not "download a copy"?

Comment: What do you mean not "download a copy"? The very idea of being able to view something on the Internet necessitates downloading it. If you only want users to be able to use it as a data source, I think you need to go to SSAS. If the issue is that you don't want users to be able to change the reports ***even if they download a copy***, then I think  you would need to look at Information Rights Management.

Comment: I don't think it should necessitate being able to download. I would like users to be able to view the document in Excel Services, and to be able to create a data connection (from Excel or Power View) that references the Power Pivot data. I just don't want them to be able to download the xlsx file that contains the Power Pivot model.

Comment: We are using SSAS (Tabular) as well, and we are defining the differences between Tabular and PP.  It is looking like this might be one -- if we can't prevent folks from downloading a Power Pivot cube.

Comment: This is a fundamental aspect of the Internet. If a person has read access to a file, they can download it.

Comment: @RobertKaucher That is true for static file types such as Word or PDF, for which the entire source file must be transferred to the client in order to be displayed. But it's not true for *data sources*, such as PP. If I create a new Excel doc with a data connection to a published Power Pivot file, then only the data that meets the query criteria must be transferred.  That is, I don't need to transfer the entire Power Pivot source file (xlsx) to the client.

Comment: I understand, but if the person has read access to the PP source Excel file then they will be able to download it end of discussion. The PP file is both an Excel file and a data source.

Comment: @RobertKaucher Right, so we agree on SharePoint's current behavior. But I believe that it should be *possible* to separate *download* permission from *connection* permission, even if it's not currently implemented.

Comment: Understood. I'm saying that is not possible given the current model under which PP operates because it is both an Excel file and a DS. Unless there is another way to publish your model, the download of the `.xlsx` is built into the architecture... I'm not in any way trying to be rude and I'm sorry  if it seems that way. It's just that since it is also a file it must obey the rules of a file.

Comment: Sure, I got it.  And no, I didn't think you were being rude -- I appreciate your insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this link - [Disable Send To and Download a Copy options for files?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17599/disable-send-to-and-download-a-copy-options-for-files) - it's not possible.

<s>Go to the list and go to List Permissions, break inheritance and set the users/groups of your choosing to only have read permissions. This will make it possible for them to see the items in the list but not interact with them.</s>